# Telerik radcombobox is Causing Chrome Browser to Freeze

Tags: google-chrome, combobox, telerik, freeze, telerik-combobox

I'm using a telerik radcombobox inside an updatepanel which is inside a radpageview of radmultipage.

Hierarchy Example (not actual code):

```
<telerik:radmultipage>
   <telerik:radpageview>
      <asp:updatepanel>
         <telerik:radcombobox><telerik:radcombobox>
      </asp:updatepanel>
   </telerik:radpageview>
</telerik:radmultipage>
```

From the rendered page, I am able to open up the combobox and see it's many entries.  However, upon clicking on an entry to select it, then Chrome freezes (it gets slow)--usually for 30 seconds.

Yes, the serverside callback from event `onselectedindexchanged` is called very quickly, without delay.  I haven't found serverside bottle necks.  Thus, the problem appears to be in the browser.  In fact, to confirm the browser is frozen, I execute some code in Chrome's console (via developer tools) and it doesn't execute until the browser unfreezes.

**Using**

- Chrome: Version 27.0.1453.116 m
- ASP.NET Forms
- Telerik.Web.UI.dll (2010.1.519.35)

**Chrome's Dev Tools: Network**
Request speed is great except for Receiving

- Blocking 0ms
- Sending 1ms
- Waiting 54ms
- Receiving 29 s (HUGE JUMP)

**Chrome's Dev Tools: Profile**
A great percentage of time is spent in:

- set innerHTML
- a.RadComboBox._onDropDownClick
- a.RadComboBox._hideDropDown
- a.RadComboBox._removeEmTagsFromAllItems

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem could not be reproduced with Chrome Canary (v30.0.1552.0 canary)!  The following articles describe this as a Chrome bug when using innerHTML property.

One guys says, "*Its fixed in the dev channel, V28, however as i understand it it's not in beta yet.*"

**Google Chrome 26 performance issue - April 9, 2013**
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/google-chrome-26-performance-issue.aspx

**XSSAuditor performance regression in M26 - April 11, 2013**
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230504

The fix should be coming shortly from Chrome team. :)